# Mixed geom_line & geom_point plot: remove marker from color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I often have to use plots mixing lines and points (ggplot2), with the colors of the line representing one variable (here, "Dose"), and the shape of the points another one (here, "Treatment). Figure 1 shows what I typically get:

Figure 1: what I get

[image: Figure 1: what I get]

I like having different legends for the two variables, but would like to remove the round markers from the color scale, to only show the colors (see legend mockup below, made with Gimp). Doing so would allow me to have a clean legend, with colors and shapes clearly segregated.

Figure 2 (mockup): what I would like

[image: Figure 2 (mockup): what I would like]

Would anyone know if there is a way to do that? Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: the plots above show means and error bars, but I have the same problem with any plot mixing geom_line and geom_point, even simple ones.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you can use `show.legend=F` as an argument to `geom_point`

Comment: Try adding `+ guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))` to your plot.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Z.Lin ! Worked like a charm ! Exactly what I needed.